# Scrollable Window Height Div, with second Div occupying rest of screen space

Tags: html, css

Is this possible with just CSS?

I'm trying to section up the screen into two spaces:

1. A div on the left that is always the same height as the screen that stretches its width to its contents and handles height overflow with a scroll bar.
2. A div that occupies the remaining screen width, that wraps its contents, and whose height is at least as tall as the screen height regardless of content.

Here's some sample code that I tried with my best attempt ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTFta/)):

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="items">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>stuff stss fsfs sfafa sfsfa fsfafafa</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="container">This should expand rest of page width.</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
#items {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: solid 1px red;
    float: left;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    float: left;
}
```

This is very close, but it fails since the second div (blue border) fails to expand the whole remaining screen width.  I do not want to set % widths or give a fixed width to either, as I want the first div to expand its width based on its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll; // or not if you don't want it to
}
```

Comment: This also seems very close, but it appears that the left most edge of the right div doesn't meet up with the right most edge of the left div unless the resolution is super small.

Comment: Not sure this is possible without a fixed width on the right div or JS to grab the computed width.

Comment: OK thanks, I'm going to add a fixed-width on left, and make the left on the right meet up there.